# Custom Content Provider - saving images

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I keep on getting a FileNotFoundException / IOException,

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString()
            + "/Android/data/<package>");

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        boolean x = directory.mkdirs();
        Log.d(TAG, "directory: " + x);
    } 

    File path = new File(directory.getPath() , uri.getEncodedPath());


    int imode = 0;
    if (mode.contains("w")) {
        imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE;
        if (!path.exists()) {

            try {

            path.createNewFile();



            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());

            }
        }
    }
    if (mode.contains("r"))
        imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY;
    if (mode.contains("+"))
        imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_APPEND;

    return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(path, imode);
```

The exception is

```
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1115)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at com.hair.android.camera.ImageContentProvider.openFile(ImageContentProvider.java:230)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.content.ContentProvider.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:726)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:247)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:534)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:402)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:378)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at com.hair.android.HairAppActivity.onActivityResult(HairAppActivity.java:428)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4541)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2740)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2787)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1032)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-12 15:01:10.360: WARN/System.err(18679):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any ideas how I can solve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString()
```

That not correct - use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

Comment: Tried your suggestion - new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ ... Same problem. Does anyone have a working example?

Comment: Try this code http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-saving-a-sound-file-to-sd-from-resource-and-setting-as-ringtone/ and then use Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                "your_file_name")))